# Как узнать первую цифру элемента массива?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Друзья, как узнать первую цифру элемента массива? 
С последней  я разобрался, а вот с первой затруднения.

например, дан массив `a=[352, 234,745,853]`

вывести `3, 2, 7 ,8`

Comment: Преобразованием числа в строку и получением первого символа строки, например.

Comment: Кто голосовал за закрытие, отпишитесь с комментарием, что вам не нравится в вопросе. На мой взгляд, вопрос хороший, непростой, разве что массив тут не к месту.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вариант Владимира Мартьянова из комментариев (о преобразовании в строку и выборке символа на первой позиции) хороший.

Альтернативно можно делать так:

1. Если число равно нулю, то выводим 0, берём следующее число и снова проверяем. Когда число перестанет быть 0, переходим к пункту 2
2. Находим от числа десятичный логарифм
3. Отбрасываем мантиссу (получается число, равное разрядности - 1)
4. Возводим 10 в полученную степень
5. Отбрасываем мантиссу (потому что `Math.pow` возвращает `double`)
6. Делим исходное число на полученное в пункте 5 (получается первая цифра)

Такой код:

```
int a[] = {352, 2354,745,853};
for (int i : a) {
    if (i==0) {
        System.out.println(0);
        continue;
    }
    if ( i == Integer.MIN_VALUE ) {
        System.out.println(2);
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(i / (int)Math.pow(10, ((int)(Math.log10(Math.abs(i))))));
}
```

Output:

```
3
2
7
8
```

#### UPDATE

Как подсказал @VladD, нужно отдельно рассмотреть случай с `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Дело в том, что `Math.abs` при `i < 0` возвращает `-i`, а для `int` это уже выход за пределы 2147483647. Поэтому число возвращается на свою отрицательную позицию.

Comment: `Math.log10(Math.abs(i))` в одном хитром случае вылетит :)

Comment: @VladD, в нуле? Я его рассмотрел отдельно.

Comment: Не, [в `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5444611/276994).

Comment: @VladD, поправил, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! (Я только что попал в такую же ловушку.)

Answer (score 8):

Еще один вариант:

1. Проверяем, превышает ли число 10 (включительно)
2. Если да, делим на 10 без остатка и GOTO 1.
3. Если нет, выводим как результат.

Код:

```
int a[] = {352, 2354, 745, 853};
for (int i : a) {
    // если число может быть отрицательным, добавляем следующую строку.
    i = Math.abs(i)
    while (i >= 10) {
        i = i / 10;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

```
3
2
7
8
```

---

Я надеюсь, выводить в одну строку и с рандомными запятыми (`3, 2, 7 ,8`) это не обязательное требование? =)

Comment: `i = Math.abs(i)` не вполне верно. Угадаете, для какого значения `i`?

Comment: @VladD точнее minint, но суть понятна. ) подумаю еще, как его красиво  обработать.

Comment: Именно! [15 символов]

Answer (score 5):

Реализация по мотивам `Integer.toString` и компании. В принципе, тот же логарифм, но по таблице.

```
final static int[] placements = new int[] {
    0,
    9, 99, 999,
    9_999, 99_999, 999_999,
    9_999_999, 99_999_999, 999_999_999,
    Integer.MAX_VALUE
};

static int firstDigit( int number ) {
    // т.к. Math.abs( Integer.MIN_VALUE ) == Integer.MIN_VALUE
    // выносим в отдельную проверку
    if ( number == Integer.MIN_VALUE ) return 2;
    number = Math.abs( number );

    int position = 1;
    while ( number > placements[position] ) {
        position++;
    }
    return number / (placements[position-1]+1);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a[] = {352, 2354, 745, 853};


    // Ня! Стримы!
    System.out.println( 
        Arrays.stream( a ).map( n -> firstDigit( n ) )
            .mapToObj( Integer::toString ).collect( Collectors.joining( ", " ) )
      );
}
```

Comment: О, вы не попали в ловушку. +1.

Comment: Это потому, что я в процессе теста оттоптался по `for( int n = 0; n <= Integer.MAX_VALUE; n++ )` :)